# VSCode is not being able to detect errors in Angular before compiling

Tags: angular, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

My Angular application was running right since I restarted `Visual Studio Code`, now the IDE does not warn about any errors with the `red line error warning` but accuses them all only when I execute the application with `ng serve`.

- Lateral Sidebar (everything's green):

[image]

- Terminal Output (a lot of errors) :

[image]

Comment: it's seems your `tsconfig.ts` is not properly configurated. It seems your are exporting a component but the compiler doesn't see it

Answer (score 0):

You can try out a few steps to fix this issue:

1. Check Typescript Version compatibility: The version of Typescript used by visual studio code for your project should be aligned with the version specified in your project's package.json file
2. Check tsconfig.json: Ensure that the "strict" option is set to true
   for stricter type checking.
3. Recreate Node Modules: you can try deleting the node_modules directory and the package-lock.json file, and then run npm install to reinstall them and load the application

Also make sure you have installed the angular language service extension.

You can also create a new angular project and check if the same issue persist or its due to your current project settings.